# Odds to get the usually excluded upper-bound with Math.random()

Tags: javascript

This may look more like a math question but as it is exclusively linked to Javascript's pseudo-random number generator I guess it is a good fit for SO. If not, feel free to move it elsewhere.

First off, I'm aware that ES does not specify the algorithm to be used in the pseudo-random number generator - `Math.random()` -, but it does specify that the range should have an approximate uniform distribution:

> ### [15.8.2.14 random ( )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.14)
>
> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with **approximately uniform distribution over that range**, using an implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy. This function takes no arguments.

So far, so good. Now I've recently stumbled upon this piece of data from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

> Note that as numbers in JavaScript are IEEE 754 floating point numbers with round-to-nearest-even behavior, these ranges, excluding the one for `Math.random()` itself, aren't exact, and depending on the bounds it's possible in extremely rare cases (on the order of **1 in 2^62**) to calculate the usually-excluded upper bound.

Okay. It led me to some testing, the results are (obviously) the same on Chrome console and Firefox's Firebug:

```
>> 0.99999999999999995
1
>> 0.999999999999999945
1
>> 0.999999999999999944
0.9999999999999999
```

Let's put it in a simple practical example to make my question more clear:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 1)
```

Considering the code above, IEEE 754 floating point numbers with round-to-nearest-even behavior, under the assessment of `Math.random()` range being evenly distributed, I concluded that the odds for it to return the usually excluded upper bound (`1` in my code above) would be `0.000000000000000055555...`, that is approximately `1/18,000,000,000,000,000`.

Looking at the MDN number now, `1/2^62` evaluates to `1/4,611,686,018,427,387,904`, that is, over 200 times smaller than the result from my calc.

Am I doing the wrong math? Is Firefox's pseudo-random number generator just not evenly distributed enough as to generate this 200 times difference?

I know how to work around this and I'm aware that such small odds shouldn't even be considered for every day's uses, but I'd love to understand what is going on here and if my math is broken or Mozilla's (I hope it is former). `=]` Any input is appreciated.

Comment: From what I can remember the distribution on all implementations of `Math.random` was not even at all and could be beat with a function directly implemented from wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks, you always provide very useful ES/JS related data on my questions @Esailija `=]`

Comment: This may be a little off but, `Math.pow(2, 62).toString(2)` returns 63 bits, however JS would round up to the upper bound at the 54th positive bit though. Not sure if this calc is right either. Guess I need to dig in deeper.

Comment: `.toString(2)` is not related to digital bits, it's binary numeral system conversion. So it works even with `Math.pow(2,1000).toString(2)` and so on

Comment: Binaries are unrelated to bits, oh of course, damn my stupidity. JavaScript uses IEEE-754 compliant floating-point doubles which have 53 bits mantissa, I should've realized that there would be no way to get 63 bits out of that. @Esailija The cause of the rounding problem would be that `Math.random()` constructs a double with more than 53 bits right? I'm taking a look at `/js/src/jsmath.cpp` of Firefox 18, but my c++ skills can't find anything leading to that.

Comment: Now I'm confused, how come bits (binary digits) are different from digital bits? Just in that binary conversion can represent numbers in binary that are not accurately represented by JS floats? Or they're completely unrelated?

Comment: Yes, `toString(2)` is completely unrelated to the actual binaries behind a JS float. `Math.pow(2,1000).toString(2).length` is `1001`... but the amount of actual bits under a double is always 64.

Comment: Thanks, it is crystal clear now. `=]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be worried about rounding the number from Math.random() up to 1.

When I was looking at the implementation (inferred from results I am getting) in the current versions of IE, Chrome, and FF, there are several observations that almost certainly mean that you should always get a number in the interval 0 to 0.11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 in binary (which is `0.999999999999999944.toString(2)` and a few smaller decimal numbers too btw.).

**Chrome:** Here it is simple. It generates numbers by generating 32 bit number and dividing it by 1 << 32. (You can see that `(1 << 30) * 4 * Math.random()` always return a whole number).

**FF:** Here it seems that the number is always generated to be at most the 0.11... (53x 1) and it really uses just those 53 decimal places. (You can see that `Math.random().toString(2).length - 2` does not return more than 53).

**IE:** Here it is very similar to FF, except that the number of places can be more if the first digits after a decimal dot are 0 and those will not round to 1 for sure. (You can see that `Math.random().toString(2).match(/1[01]*$/)[0].length` does not return more than 53).

I think (although I cannot provide any proof now) that any implementation should fall to one of those described groups and have no problem with rounding to 1.

Comment: `+1` Very useful data, thanks. For this question I'm scoping it mostly to the Firefox implementation as the data comes from MDN and other JS implementations (including closed source ones) will vary. Though it is great to have data on other implementations. `=]` Just one thing though, before you call `.toString(2)` the result from `Math.random()` would already have suffered rounding to fit in JS's 53 bits mantissa, wouldn't it?

Comment: Also looking at [this link](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-randm.htm#TRn2): "For `Math.random()`, MS IE 8 shows '1' bits to bit53, and for bit54 except for when BIT 1 is set (random value ≥ 0.5). Firefox and Opera are good, with '1' bits to bit53. Safari and Chrome show '1' bits to bit32. (2010-12-09, current browser releases.)" everything matches your answer so far.

Comment: Exactly for that reason that the mantissa is just a sequence of known number of bits the random number generator would get only worse (both in terms of efficiency and the problem with rounding) if it did not treat it as such. Btw. most rounding in your examples is of a different kind - rounding while parsing a decimal representation. You can see that 0.999999999999999944 === 0.999999999999999834.

Comment: Yeah, as `0.999999999999999944` evaluates to `0.9999999999999999` exactly as `0.999999999999999834` does. Only one question left before I mark your answer as accepted, if you look at the question's comments, the `.toString(2)` method which you use seems to be unrelated to the digital bits/mantissa. It is weird how it matches your result and my linked page's results above though. Is there any relation between the binary representation and the mantissa which I'm missing?

Comment: The problem with decimal representation is that it does not map well to the internal binary form.. so 0.999999999999999944 does not really evaluate to 0.9999999999999999, but to a mantissa full of 1s, which is not the same number. One good example is .2.toString(2), which shows that 0.2 is only approximate in the binary representation (it is a periodical number there). when you use .toString(2), the situation is different, as the digits shown represent mantissa, because no information needs to be 'lost' when printing, but 'padded' with 0s according to exponent (and showing leading 'hidden' 1).